# Obtaining a list of all files uniquely that are part of a commit

Tags: git, tar

I have the following command:

`git archive HEAD | tar -xC GitPulls/`

This gets everything from `HEAD` and places it in the previously empty `/GitPulls/` folder. The folder now contains many different files - say 1000 files.

I want to get a flat text list of exactly these 1000 files with no repetition -- that is, I want a list of files that `git archive HEAD | tar -xC GitPulls/` will place in the `/GitPulls/` folder.

I tried `git log --name-only`. However, this provides output that repeats the same file multiple times -- presumably for each time that the file was modified and staged and committed.

How would this change if I wanted only the contents of a specific previous commit and not the `HEAD`? That is, how can I obtain the unique list of files that would be unzipped into the `/GitPulls/` folder on running the following: `git archive <SHAID> | tar -xC GitPulls/`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+files+commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command should do:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only <commit-id>
```

Comment: Ah, this is very useful. I had previously tried git ls-tree HEAD (without the -r) and was surprised at the low number of entries returned. So, recursive -r does it.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the unique entries of `git log --name-only` should correspond to the list returned by `git ls-tree -r HEAD`?

Comment: @Tryer: `git log --name-only` will also list files that were previously commited and are gone in the current commit. `git ls-tree` will only list files that are currently present. That's because `git log` acts on the whole history (the current and previous commits) and `git ls-tree` only looks at the specified commit/tree (the current one in this example).

Comment: That's not fair to say. `git log` is expected to show what is changed from the previous commit (I definitely want to see _only_ the list of changed files when looking at log.... don't want to get the same full list of files in log for every commit... then I wouldn't even know what files were changed), whereas you want the full listing of a commit.... so it has to be done some other way.

Comment: @eftshift0 Is it possible to list which was the last commit that updated a particular file in question? For instance, `git ls-tree -r --someotheroption HEAD | grep interested_file` ?
In looking at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree it is not clear to me how to find the most recent commit that updated the `interested_file` in the example above.

Comment: You can run log on the file and it will list commits where it was modified... if you use `-n 1` it will list _the last_ commit where it was modified.